# Joining data together by id that is not unique

Tags: mysql, pivot, one-to-many

Say I have two tables as outlined below:

```
mysql> show columns from ping;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ping_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| msg_size   | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| version    | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| num_points | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lat_deg    | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lat_min    | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| long_deg   | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| long_min   | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| bearing    | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pitch      | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| roll       | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| heave      | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tide       | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| hour       | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| min        | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sec        | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| day        | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| month      | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| year       | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| posx       | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| posy       | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pingtime   | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
22 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

and:

```
mysql> show columns from point;
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| point_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ping_id  | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| x        | float            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| y        | float            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| texture  | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| fish     | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Ping_id for the table ping is unique. However ping_id for point is not. IE there are several points for each ping_id. I need to select data so that there is several x,y columns for each ping (number of points are not constant). IE, I am looking for an output that looks like this:

```
+----------+------------------+-----------+-----+-----+----+------+----+----+-----+----+
| ping_id  | lat_deg          | lon_deg    | x1 | y1  | x2 | y2   | x3 | y3 | x4 | y4 | 
+----------+------------------+------------+-----+-----+----+-----+----+----+----+-----+
```

Comment: You would traverse the one->many relationship from the many end thereby 'selecting all points, where ping_id = id'. but how you display the information returned is up to you. Sorry but my sql scripting isn't up to scratch. so can construct an example for you.

Comment: I think it's very difficult (or impossible) to try add dynamically columns to query in mysql (maby it's possible when you user stored procedure never tried). Rather than that you should join tables and group them in some language you use. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join tables:

```
SELECT pg.ping_id, lat_deg, long_deg, p.x, p.y 
FROM ping pg 
JOIN point p ON p.ping_id = pg.ping_id
```

and process results to get grouped points for example in PHP:

```
$pings = array();
foreach($results as $row){
  $pings[$row['ping_id']][] = $row;
}
```

Comment: your statement does not transverse the table point table though. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM point JOIN ping on point.ping_id = point.ping_id WHERE point.ping_id = ?